# How can I avoid overflow in my IsNumberPolyndrom function

Tags: c, overflow

I'm practicing some c questions, and I wanted to make a function that checks if a giving value is a palindrome or not without using mod .
But- I am worried about overflow in my function IsNumPalindrome.

Would love to get some input on how to make this code better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 /*function returns mod, divider must be different than zero */

int GetMod(int number, int divider)
{

    return(number- (divider*(number/divider)));
}

/* function return 1 if palindrome 0 if not*/
int IsNumberPalindrome(int number)
{
    int saveOriginal = 0;
    int reminder = 0;
    int reversedNum = 0;

    saveOriginal = number ;
    while (0 < number)
    {
        reminder = GetMod(number, 10);
        number /= 10;
        reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + reminder;
    }

    return(saveOriginal == reversedNum);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    i= IsNumberPalindrome(154);
    printf("Is pal for 154 %d\n", i);
    i = IsNumberPalindrome(3003);
    printf("Is pal for 3003 %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you ask this question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. They specialize on critiquing completed code there, while StackOverflow is more for people needing help with a specific problem with their code.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using a specially-made function for getting the remainder instead of just using the modulus operator `%`?

Comment: That was a requirement of the question I found- I guess to give it an extra twist. And I wasn't sure if this type of Q is welcomed there @Abion47

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call this kind of question "unwelcome", as it does seem to be toeing the line between asking about a problem and asking for a code review. But as this code is (presumably) functional and you are just asking how you can improve it, my gut tells me that you would likely get better answers over there.

Comment: `reversedNum` *could* overflow. Suppose a 32-bit input is `1133557799` its reversal `9977553311` overflows.

Comment: There are better (or at least less complicated) ways of doing this especially given the constraint. How about converting the number to string and checking *that* for being polyndrom?

Comment: That is an awesome  idea! Thank you!!! @EugeneSh.